# ASP MVC и Ajax post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Занимаюсь изучением `ASP MVC` и столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на ячейку таблицы из представления посылался запрос в контроллер, который возвращает `PartialView` и отображает его на странице. Отправка запроса в контроллер:

```
$('td').click(function() {
$.ajax({
url: '/Home/OneDay',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'html',
success: function(data){ 
$().html(data);
}})});
```

Сам контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OneDay(string id)
{       
return PartialView();
}
```

Проблема в том, что отправленное в ответ частичное представление не отображается на странице.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из документации по jQuery: `.html(string) Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.` (Устанавливает HTML всем найденным элементам)

```
success: function(data){ 
  $().html(data);
}
```

Вы элементы не ищите `$().html(data);`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.